# How to combine 'tail -f' and 'grep' in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

When I do

```
tail -f file.log
```

in bash every change of the file is shown on screen. But instead of listing every line of the file I only want to show lines containing a special string like `special string`.
So I tried

```
grep 'special string' file.log | tail -f
```

but this command returns to the bash immediately, not showing any future changes in the file.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 11):

```
tail -f file.log | grep 'special string'
```

Easy, huh :)

The problem with your order is that grep doesn't have tails ability to "follow".

Comment: Oh well, yes...   Maybe its getting too late... Thanks

Comment: @Alex =} ... fairy nuff.

Comment: keep in mind, however, that buffering will play a significant factor here... a single new occurrence of `'special string'` may not be immediately output and may only show up much later after the pipe buffer between `tail` and `grep` fills sufficiently...

Comment: @twalberg - that's true, but will need to be addressed at the level of the program generating file.log, as tail -f will flush line-buffered.